# PHP getopt $longopts - required + boolean

Tags: php, getopt

Can somebody explain me please how PHP handles getopt() $longopts parameters?
Documentation says there can be defined required and optional parameters. But I dont understand what it means required if it is not required. If I write this code:

```
getopt(null, ['lang:', 'optional'])
```

I expect the missing --lang parameter throws me an error. Am I missing something? Also I dont understand how to send boolean TRUE/FALSE to the script.

Answer (score 1):

It is the value of the parameter that is required or optional, not the parameter itself.

Required means you have to pass the value after the parameter

```
$program --lang en
```

while

```
$program --lang
```

is error.

If it is optional the value may or may not be provided.

If your parameter doesn't expect a value at all, it is your responsibility to exit with error.

If you need a parameter to be always present, it is also your responsibilty to check if that parameter is present once you called getopt.

Comment: The probleem is $program --lang without param is not an error. But as I see it gobbles other parameters after required one like 
$program --lang --test="whatever" results in $lang = "--test...."

Comment: But thanks for the answer you confirmed my worries.